# Laravel where :: model, how to add multi statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So how i can add multi statement to query in ::where model.

Actually it lok like that:
    certs::where('unique', '=', $newUnique )->get()

i need somethig like that:

```
certs::where('unique, num', '=', $newUnique,$key )->get()
```

so in sql look like that

```
Select * From certs Where unique = $newUnique AND num = $key
```

I need that to check if data need to be updated or inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append another where clause

```php
certs::where('unique', $newUnique)->where('num', $key)->get()
```

For example

```
App\User::where('first_name', 'John')->where('last_name', 'Doe')->toSql();
```

Would result in

```
"select * from `users` where `first_name` = ? and `last_name` = ?"
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

It can become tricky if there will be OR instead of AND, so you should always prefer

for AND

```
Certs::where(function($query) use ([$newUnique, $key]){ 
    $query->where('first_name', 'John')->where('last_name', 'Doe');
})->get();
```

for OR

```
Certs::where(function($query) use ([$newUnique, $key]){ 
    $query->where('first_name', 'John')->orWhere('last_name', 'Doe');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel allows multi statements for "where" function of Model by passing array of conditions.

The below code can be used if you are applying **"and" condition and "=" operation** for each data.

```
$conditions = ['unique'=>$newUnique,'num'=>$key];
Certs::where($conditions)->get();
```

Else if you want to use different operations with **"and" condition**, use below code.

```
$conditions = [
     ['unique','=',$newUnique],['num','!=',$key]
];
Certs::where($conditions)->get();
```

Also, you can use below code for **"and" and "or" conditions**.

```
Certs::where(function($query) use ($newUnique, $key]){ 
    $query->where('unique', $newUnique);
    $query->orWhere('num', $key);

})->get();
```

Similarly, you can use orWhere(), whereColumn(), whereBetween() and other query builder functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
certs::where(['unique'=>$newUnique, 'num' => $key])->get()
```